# как в python сделать постоянное добавление новых переменных для одной и той же команды

Tags: python

у меня есть команда

```
print(jwl[0] + '  ' + rwl[0] + '  ' + tl[0])
```

где jwl, rwl, tl - это списки. Как мне сделать, чтобы номер элемента постоянно менялся, то есть я хочу, чтобы у меня выводилось:

```
print(jwl[1] + '  ' + rwl[1] + '  ' + tl[1])
print(jwl[2] + '  ' + rwl[2] + '  ' + tl[2])
print(jwl[3] + '  ' + rwl[3] + '  ' + tl[3])
```

Но проблема в том, что у меня большой список, который будет постоянно обновляться, то есть там будут новые элементы, и постоянно писать print для каждого - очень долго. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Цикл можно сделать.

Comment: а какой? Можно подробнее, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного непонятно насчет вывода после обновления. Нужно выводить все значения или только измененные. Если все, то можно просто циклом

```
for i in range(len(jwl)):
    print(jwl[i] + '  ' + rwl[i] + '  ' + tl[i])
```

Но стоит уточнить, что данный способ валиден только при равной длине списков, и если используете python3, то более элегантно будет:

```
for i in range(len(jwl)):
    print(jwl[i],rwl[i],tl[i],sep=' ')
```